# CSS position: sticky; Как зафиксировать элемент в нижней части при скроле?

Tags: css3, sticky

Есть вот такой простой пример.

```css
.bl_seo {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn_elements {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00BADBFF;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_seo">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos voluptatem voluptatibus corporis perferendis mollitia aperiam nesciunt ipsum, quaerat consectetur nihil officia commodi a, perspiciatis quae velit nulla accusamus maiores explicabo?</div>
  <div>Saepe totam expedita minima, a quasi aut aliquam necessitatibus! Ipsam voluptate quasi ex aliquam sequi, officiis voluptas nihil iste eaque, unde voluptates nemo distinctio laboriosam ut quod quisquam debitis vitae!</div>
  <div>Totam autem accusantium ex libero, asperiores cum porro amet modi temporibus provident ad aspernatur, officia perspiciatis eaque fuga commodi tenetur placeat harum nisi rerum molestias. Unde sed officiis suscipit facere.</div>
  <div>Ea dolorum dolor asperiores quibusdam nam magni accusamus consectetur eius, laudantium porro dolore inventore sunt odio tempore doloremque similique nobis officia, placeat ex? Atque, maxime quod provident aut ullam, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Quis fuga maiores commodi nihil recusandae aliquam pariatur dolorem ex earum molestiae, molestias. Ullam reprehenderit, consequuntur accusamus adipisci nostrum. Quam similique hic iusto consequatur corporis blanditiis iure voluptatem ducimus doloremque.</div>
  <div>Ducimus maxime quidem dolorum esse, voluptatum in expedita voluptates doloribus itaque similique ut delectus adipisci, ea architecto accusantium consequatur sunt autem placeat dicta! Dolorum quam adipisci omnis asperiores! Eos, asperiores.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, quo earum fugiat delectus, labore sapiente iusto. Incidunt nulla cum voluptate pariatur itaque ducimus magnam qui quis dicta quidem odio provident fugit excepturi vero quia, rem assumenda. Dolore, explicabo!</div>
  <div>Excepturi earum et consequuntur eos temporibus ad ipsam accusamus ex fuga voluptate totam mollitia dolorum dolore nisi, facilis inventore harum qui neque eaque ratione at! Vero beatae ipsam temporibus aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Deserunt sequi labore ea molestias quia saepe aspernatur quo praesentium, maiores consequuntur cumque, tempora non. Soluta mollitia aliquam dolor consequatur laudantium eligendi sequi dolorem, quae rem labore. Repudiandae, facilis iste.</div>
  <div>Autem consequuntur perferendis incidunt sed, esse aperiam ab, placeat laboriosam reiciendis asperiores debitis obcaecati. Molestiae iure labore perferendis saepe, natus eaque ad eligendi incidunt soluta, perspiciatis enim possimus voluptatum dicta!</div>
  <div>Dolor adipisci in ullam, error quam assumenda repellendus quidem a? Qui voluptas praesentium saepe quas amet necessitatibus perspiciatis placeat fuga vitae nemo, hic nisi eius, aliquid quia ab error illo.</div>
  <div>Beatae consequuntur culpa enim eaque adipisci totam! Praesentium voluptatem dolor quia cupiditate. Cum, qui, corporis! Nihil ratione ducimus labore nesciunt explicabo ipsam quisquam! Sunt animi temporibus aliquam magnam corrupti ipsum.</div>
  <div>Impedit cum, labore in nisi fuga numquam, iure quam adipisci deserunt repellat, perferendis. Nostrum in sequi explicabo eum et voluptas soluta, similique ratione ab quaerat, quam unde aut fugit dolores.</div>
  <div>Soluta placeat incidunt, optio consequatur, libero nesciunt adipisci unde repellat enim aspernatur aut earum! Vitae earum fugit eveniet blanditiis, recusandae a. Consequuntur, vitae ratione molestiae. Obcaecati suscipit possimus placeat, itaque.</div>
  <div>Molestias at commodi ipsum debitis magni quisquam aperiam optio deserunt tenetur eaque. Aspernatur accusamus ullam laudantium, blanditiis, deserunt totam voluptates quas nostrum enim non quos obcaecati minus iure maiores dignissimos.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos voluptatem voluptatibus corporis perferendis mollitia aperiam nesciunt ipsum, quaerat consectetur nihil officia commodi a, perspiciatis quae velit nulla accusamus maiores explicabo?</div>
  <div>Saepe totam expedita minima, a quasi aut aliquam necessitatibus! Ipsam voluptate quasi ex aliquam sequi, officiis voluptas nihil iste eaque, unde voluptates nemo distinctio laboriosam ut quod quisquam debitis vitae!</div>
  <div>Totam autem accusantium ex libero, asperiores cum porro amet modi temporibus provident ad aspernatur, officia perspiciatis eaque fuga commodi tenetur placeat harum nisi rerum molestias. Unde sed officiis suscipit facere.</div>
  <div>Ea dolorum dolor asperiores quibusdam nam magni accusamus consectetur eius, laudantium porro dolore inventore sunt odio tempore doloremque similique nobis officia, placeat ex? Atque, maxime quod provident aut ullam, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Quis fuga maiores commodi nihil recusandae aliquam pariatur dolorem ex earum molestiae, molestias. Ullam reprehenderit, consequuntur accusamus adipisci nostrum. Quam similique hic iusto consequatur corporis blanditiis iure voluptatem ducimus doloremque.</div>
  <div>Ducimus maxime quidem dolorum esse, voluptatum in expedita voluptates doloribus itaque similique ut delectus adipisci, ea architecto accusantium consequatur sunt autem placeat dicta! Dolorum quam adipisci omnis asperiores! Eos, asperiores.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, quo earum fugiat delectus, labore sapiente iusto. Incidunt nulla cum voluptate pariatur itaque ducimus magnam qui quis dicta quidem odio provident fugit excepturi vero quia, rem assumenda. Dolore, explicabo!</div>
  <div>Excepturi earum et consequuntur eos temporibus ad ipsam accusamus ex fuga voluptate totam mollitia dolorum dolore nisi, facilis inventore harum qui neque eaque ratione at! Vero beatae ipsam temporibus aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Deserunt sequi labore ea molestias quia saepe aspernatur quo praesentium, maiores consequuntur cumque, tempora non. Soluta mollitia aliquam dolor consequatur laudantium eligendi sequi dolorem, quae rem labore. Repudiandae, facilis iste.</div>
  <div>Autem consequuntur perferendis incidunt sed, esse aperiam ab, placeat laboriosam reiciendis asperiores debitis obcaecati. Molestiae iure labore perferendis saepe, natus eaque ad eligendi incidunt soluta, perspiciatis enim possimus voluptatum dicta!</div>
  <div>Dolor adipisci in ullam, error quam assumenda repellendus quidem a? Qui voluptas praesentium saepe quas amet necessitatibus perspiciatis placeat fuga vitae nemo, hic nisi eius, aliquid quia ab error illo.</div>
  <div>Beatae consequuntur culpa enim eaque adipisci totam! Praesentium voluptatem dolor quia cupiditate. Cum, qui, corporis! Nihil ratione ducimus labore nesciunt explicabo ipsam quisquam! Sunt animi temporibus aliquam magnam corrupti ipsum.</div>
  <div>Molestias at commodi ipsum debitis magni quisquam aperiam optio deserunt tenetur eaque. Aspernatur accusamus ullam laudantium, blanditiis, deserunt totam voluptates quas nostrum enim non quos obcaecati minus iure maiores dignissimos.</div>
  <a class="btn_elements" href="/test/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Text Button</a>


  <div>Modi, doloremque dolores quas, expedita sint, deserunt perspiciatis repellendus tenetur neque repellat sit error harum perferendis provident enim rem in. Consequatur nostrum error praesentium unde, vel voluptas ea quae neque.</div>
  <div>Ullam maxime atque delectus inventore, esse, cum, est soluta, dicta omnis placeat ducimus vel eveniet perspiciatis aperiam distinctio minima minus! Magnam fugiat nulla natus, quis doloremque? Ullam nesciunt, atque a.</div>
  <div>Voluptatem est, fugiat dignissimos consequuntur ut rerum rem doloribus blanditiis perferendis tempora expedita recusandae placeat voluptatum esse sit unde, sint culpa saepe error architecto soluta itaque fuga minima. Perferendis, praesentium!</div>
  <div>Earum cupiditate, minus dolorem harum aliquam qui aspernatur illum recusandae officia laborum ullam incidunt deserunt? Quibusdam qui odit earum, minima ea molestiae ad, dolorem unde, voluptatibus repellat accusantium dicta harum.</div>
  <div>Aliquam reiciendis laboriosam aliquid illo saepe, earum est voluptatibus, nostrum, dolorem similique, rerum? Culpa laudantium repellat similique! Blanditiis, neque aliquam harum atque, aspernatur maxime porro totam, nulla quibusdam voluptatibus itaque.</div>
  <div>Provident expedita, quo temporibus soluta voluptas, dolor dolorem quod voluptate eum, modi quibusdam a dicta doloremque neque voluptatum rerum totam sit vel blanditiis at quasi. Soluta unde dolores libero porro!</div>
  <div>Dolorum eius fugiat vel, suscipit repellat mollitia quas at facilis alias dignissimos illum quod, tempora ad ullam similique voluptates ea laboriosam possimus quia. Sit harum quam pariatur, suscipit libero inventore!</div>
  <div>Quod pariatur, natus minus doloribus nobis! Cum illo, repellat molestiae reiciendis quibusdam minus atque itaque dignissimos voluptatum quaerat magni quo debitis enim vel numquam. Laudantium, iste, soluta! Ipsum officia, odit!</div>
  <div>Explicabo quas possimus, iure hic reiciendis laudantium illum, natus minima! Quam blanditiis porro, placeat dolore in nesciunt numquam mollitia molestias? Qui quasi rem ut obcaecati cum at, corrupti adipisci aperiam.</div>
  <div>Inventore fugiat, ab reprehenderit quod sapiente! Corrupti, reprehenderit voluptatibus deleniti laboriosam, quod omnis neque itaque! Id eveniet facere ut, ducimus laborum nemo laboriosam voluptatibus ex ipsa reiciendis animi incidunt mollitia.</div>
  <div>Sapiente dignissimos repellat fugit excepturi beatae provident saepe, at eligendi voluptatum nesciunt ullam, nobis eius perspiciatis voluptatibus recusandae quia cupiditate possimus cumque eos quod aliquam harum. Minima ex labore amet.</div>
  <div>Minima voluptatem ex accusantium qui perspiciatis, officia, totam harum fugit nisi neque minus a illo voluptates quas dicta magnam obcaecati aut quos nemo veniam ducimus quam sequi similique unde laudantium?</div>
  <div>Culpa quod blanditiis aliquam tenetur reprehenderit a vel, laboriosam unde ut molestiae. Quo quibusdam ad sapiente, nisi amet et aut error voluptatibus molestias veniam quos enim vel ipsa. Dolorem, totam?</div>
  <div>Blanditiis, quia. Blanditiis asperiores quos id, totam tenetur animi tempora, consectetur hic quidem magni iusto eveniet consequatur laboriosam quibusdam nulla sint sed, iure alias aperiam veritatis sit eaque! Ipsum, similique!</div>
  <div>Reprehenderit repellat temporibus, voluptas cupiditate in, obcaecati, totam ipsa impedit rem, consequatur maxime sequi! Quas atque harum deleniti aspernatur aliquam, ea alias perspiciatis sunt a ad at maiores impedit amet!</div>
  <div>Sint qui, accusantium libero vero autem sapiente, eum illo nihil, voluptas ipsa quia! Animi ipsa dicta aperiam et ipsum beatae autem quis quaerat sit veritatis doloribus, non, consequuntur quae quam.</div>
  <div>A eius quia hic quam asperiores ipsum eum adipisci libero, ad enim eveniet voluptatum repudiandae assumenda reiciendis sint animi recusandae illum qui doloribus ut mollitia minima ab dicta accusamus! Quos.</div>
  <div>A, quo vel quam laudantium ipsam ipsa nesciunt incidunt nemo hic, vero eum. Est quam laboriosam nobis aspernatur labore ab neque laborum inventore similique. Culpa eaque asperiores atque minus, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Soluta, voluptates, autem. Atque commodi tempore ratione, inventore perferendis voluptatum? Neque distinctio ullam tempora magni corrupti maiores repudiandae, ex minus alias eius natus veritatis enim deserunt quam odit, cumque similique.</div>
  <div>Eum quia maiores ipsum porro doloribus fuga earum nam, laborum mollitia. Veniam distinctio culpa corporis, nam asperiores molestias quidem atque, quam dolor, excepturi tempore deserunt maiores aspernatur vero aperiam voluptate?</div>
  <div>Consequuntur ab voluptatem reprehenderit cum repudiandae, officia quia alias, nemo aliquam! Sit, perferendis! Odio deleniti doloribus optio, repellendus, beatae velit in aliquam voluptatem molestias earum, dignissimos eum dolore nihil dolorum.</div>
  <div>Corrupti quaerat qui commodi, maxime quis laudantium hic veritatis nulla! Culpa vel repellendus eligendi, sit corrupti saepe nesciunt ut beatae placeat blanditiis ipsa illo delectus repellat, sapiente totam, maxime id!</div>
  <div>Nobis, ratione distinctio eum, totam odit inventore minus sint obcaecati accusamus voluptatum explicabo veritatis nostrum temporibus soluta ad sapiente at beatae mollitia consectetur expedita qui tenetur alias. Eaque, quaerat atque!</div>
  <div>Eos repudiandae architecto, ad perspiciatis iusto voluptatum dicta. Rem modi fugiat animi et, natus est id necessitatibus harum illo doloribus voluptatem eligendi aliquam quasi magni assumenda voluptatum aperiam officiis, a.</div>
  <div>Quas repellat libero ipsam odit molestias cum tempore inventore, rem magni maxime recusandae accusamus dolores sint accusantium velit, soluta labore sunt ad exercitationem. Magni similique placeat, atque beatae. Odit, nisi!</div>
  <div>Adipisci ipsum nemo saepe ad rerum, necessitatibus iste aperiam. Dolorem ex praesentium ut amet molestias velit incidunt facere officia facilis, odit sapiente aliquam voluptates qui necessitatibus eligendi assumenda ipsam quisquam.</div>
  <div>Quam, tenetur. Quaerat doloremque ex voluptates nulla numquam. Quis soluta sint natus fugit, at iste, eligendi tempore voluptatem repellat eum minima, architecto modi officiis quo. Provident reiciendis illo voluptates atque!</div>
  <div>Reiciendis quisquam labore facere reprehenderit iste aliquid eveniet doloribus iure, ea, tempore nostrum aut culpa totam nisi ipsam necessitatibus temporibus quam velit rerum commodi, debitis. Soluta quaerat rerum, odit maxime.</div>
  <div>Laudantium distinctio molestias delectus eligendi placeat voluptatum natus nobis illum pariatur odit doloribus est consequuntur dolores consectetur id provident sapiente, error et eos. Voluptas, tenetur! Delectus, eligendi! Unde consequuntur, eaque.</div>
  <div>Repellat necessitatibus, perferendis dolorum obcaecati fugiat corporis praesentium quia ipsum, ipsa quas dolore reiciendis quasi enim amet assumenda atque earum dolor debitis deleniti. Ratione repellat vero, fuga, autem obcaecati praesentium.</div>
  <div>Nesciunt debitis laboriosam repudiandae, expedita eos iste ullam, officia recusandae facilis molestias, consectetur eligendi voluptatibus omnis asperiores et minima eius ea magnam necessitatibus! Quae asperiores, qui totam iste aliquam similique.</div>
  <div>Sequi autem sapiente at, sint minima maxime officiis! Illo, doloremque voluptatem assumenda quis eos amet sapiente suscipit sunt ex maiores quas vitae nulla non repellendus officiis rem quia, eius natus.</div>
  <div>Dolorem atque magnam magni veritatis suscipit sequi saepe minima blanditiis quo, neque aperiam libero iure dolorum. Animi ex a, et alias consectetur, debitis aliquid nihil, fugiat dolor dolore repellat id.</div>
  <div>Amet, nemo nobis repellat culpa aut deserunt sit nam ullam voluptatem non, modi eaque voluptate nesciunt praesentium velit? Aperiam velit, veniam harum laborum possimus illum quos corporis? Saepe, libero aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Veniam tenetur mollitia perspiciatis obcaecati ea perferendis in, officiis placeat inventore hic eius dolor aliquid consectetur! Itaque fugiat quod aperiam? At nulla odit cum fugit molestiae, reiciendis nobis quaerat suscipit?</div>
</div>

<div class="other_block">Test 2Veniam tenetur mollitia perspiciatis obcaecati ea perferendis in, officiis placeat inventore hic eius dolor aliquid consectetur! Itaque fugiat quod aperiam? At nulla odit cum fugit molestiae, reiciendis nobis quaerat suscipit?</div>
```

В задаче необходимо фиксировать ссылку когда пользователь только доскроливает до неё, и держать её в нижней части экрана до того момента пока не проскролит полностью div `.bl_seo` Подскажите, как это реализовать средствами CSS. изменение свойства на top:0 вместо bottom: 0; не дает нужный эффект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```css
.bl_seo {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  --link-height: 64px;
}

.bl_seo::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: var(--link-height);
}

.btn_elements {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(100% - var(--link-height));
  background-color: #00BADBFF;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl_seo">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos voluptatem voluptatibus corporis perferendis mollitia aperiam nesciunt ipsum, quaerat consectetur nihil officia commodi a, perspiciatis quae velit nulla accusamus maiores explicabo?</div>
  <div>Saepe totam expedita minima, a quasi aut aliquam necessitatibus! Ipsam voluptate quasi ex aliquam sequi, officiis voluptas nihil iste eaque, unde voluptates nemo distinctio laboriosam ut quod quisquam debitis vitae!</div>
  <div>Totam autem accusantium ex libero, asperiores cum porro amet modi temporibus provident ad aspernatur, officia perspiciatis eaque fuga commodi tenetur placeat harum nisi rerum molestias. Unde sed officiis suscipit facere.</div>
  <div>Ea dolorum dolor asperiores quibusdam nam magni accusamus consectetur eius, laudantium porro dolore inventore sunt odio tempore doloremque similique nobis officia, placeat ex? Atque, maxime quod provident aut ullam, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Quis fuga maiores commodi nihil recusandae aliquam pariatur dolorem ex earum molestiae, molestias. Ullam reprehenderit, consequuntur accusamus adipisci nostrum. Quam similique hic iusto consequatur corporis blanditiis iure voluptatem ducimus doloremque.</div>
  <div>Ducimus maxime quidem dolorum esse, voluptatum in expedita voluptates doloribus itaque similique ut delectus adipisci, ea architecto accusantium consequatur sunt autem placeat dicta! Dolorum quam adipisci omnis asperiores! Eos, asperiores.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, quo earum fugiat delectus, labore sapiente iusto. Incidunt nulla cum voluptate pariatur itaque ducimus magnam qui quis dicta quidem odio provident fugit excepturi vero quia, rem assumenda. Dolore, explicabo!</div>
  <div>Excepturi earum et consequuntur eos temporibus ad ipsam accusamus ex fuga voluptate totam mollitia dolorum dolore nisi, facilis inventore harum qui neque eaque ratione at! Vero beatae ipsam temporibus aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Deserunt sequi labore ea molestias quia saepe aspernatur quo praesentium, maiores consequuntur cumque, tempora non. Soluta mollitia aliquam dolor consequatur laudantium eligendi sequi dolorem, quae rem labore. Repudiandae, facilis iste.</div>
  <div>Autem consequuntur perferendis incidunt sed, esse aperiam ab, placeat laboriosam reiciendis asperiores debitis obcaecati. Molestiae iure labore perferendis saepe, natus eaque ad eligendi incidunt soluta, perspiciatis enim possimus voluptatum dicta!</div>
  <div>Dolor adipisci in ullam, error quam assumenda repellendus quidem a? Qui voluptas praesentium saepe quas amet necessitatibus perspiciatis placeat fuga vitae nemo, hic nisi eius, aliquid quia ab error illo.</div>
  <div>Beatae consequuntur culpa enim eaque adipisci totam! Praesentium voluptatem dolor quia cupiditate. Cum, qui, corporis! Nihil ratione ducimus labore nesciunt explicabo ipsam quisquam! Sunt animi temporibus aliquam magnam corrupti ipsum.</div>
  <div>Impedit cum, labore in nisi fuga numquam, iure quam adipisci deserunt repellat, perferendis. Nostrum in sequi explicabo eum et voluptas soluta, similique ratione ab quaerat, quam unde aut fugit dolores.</div>
  <div>Soluta placeat incidunt, optio consequatur, libero nesciunt adipisci unde repellat enim aspernatur aut earum! Vitae earum fugit eveniet blanditiis, recusandae a. Consequuntur, vitae ratione molestiae. Obcaecati suscipit possimus placeat, itaque.</div>
  <div>Molestias at commodi ipsum debitis magni quisquam aperiam optio deserunt tenetur eaque. Aspernatur accusamus ullam laudantium, blanditiis, deserunt totam voluptates quas nostrum enim non quos obcaecati minus iure maiores dignissimos.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos voluptatem voluptatibus corporis perferendis mollitia aperiam nesciunt ipsum, quaerat consectetur nihil officia commodi a, perspiciatis quae velit nulla accusamus maiores explicabo?</div>
  <div>Saepe totam expedita minima, a quasi aut aliquam necessitatibus! Ipsam voluptate quasi ex aliquam sequi, officiis voluptas nihil iste eaque, unde voluptates nemo distinctio laboriosam ut quod quisquam debitis vitae!</div>
  <div>Totam autem accusantium ex libero, asperiores cum porro amet modi temporibus provident ad aspernatur, officia perspiciatis eaque fuga commodi tenetur placeat harum nisi rerum molestias. Unde sed officiis suscipit facere.</div>
  <div>Ea dolorum dolor asperiores quibusdam nam magni accusamus consectetur eius, laudantium porro dolore inventore sunt odio tempore doloremque similique nobis officia, placeat ex? Atque, maxime quod provident aut ullam, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Quis fuga maiores commodi nihil recusandae aliquam pariatur dolorem ex earum molestiae, molestias. Ullam reprehenderit, consequuntur accusamus adipisci nostrum. Quam similique hic iusto consequatur corporis blanditiis iure voluptatem ducimus doloremque.</div>
  <div>Ducimus maxime quidem dolorum esse, voluptatum in expedita voluptates doloribus itaque similique ut delectus adipisci, ea architecto accusantium consequatur sunt autem placeat dicta! Dolorum quam adipisci omnis asperiores! Eos, asperiores.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, quo earum fugiat delectus, labore sapiente iusto. Incidunt nulla cum voluptate pariatur itaque ducimus magnam qui quis dicta quidem odio provident fugit excepturi vero quia, rem assumenda. Dolore, explicabo!</div>
  <div>Excepturi earum et consequuntur eos temporibus ad ipsam accusamus ex fuga voluptate totam mollitia dolorum dolore nisi, facilis inventore harum qui neque eaque ratione at! Vero beatae ipsam temporibus aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Deserunt sequi labore ea molestias quia saepe aspernatur quo praesentium, maiores consequuntur cumque, tempora non. Soluta mollitia aliquam dolor consequatur laudantium eligendi sequi dolorem, quae rem labore. Repudiandae, facilis iste.</div>
  <div>Autem consequuntur perferendis incidunt sed, esse aperiam ab, placeat laboriosam reiciendis asperiores debitis obcaecati. Molestiae iure labore perferendis saepe, natus eaque ad eligendi incidunt soluta, perspiciatis enim possimus voluptatum dicta!</div>
  <div>Dolor adipisci in ullam, error quam assumenda repellendus quidem a? Qui voluptas praesentium saepe quas amet necessitatibus perspiciatis placeat fuga vitae nemo, hic nisi eius, aliquid quia ab error illo.</div>
  <div>Beatae consequuntur culpa enim eaque adipisci totam! Praesentium voluptatem dolor quia cupiditate. Cum, qui, corporis! Nihil ratione ducimus labore nesciunt explicabo ipsam quisquam! Sunt animi temporibus aliquam magnam corrupti ipsum.</div>
  <div>Molestias at commodi ipsum debitis magni quisquam aperiam optio deserunt tenetur eaque. Aspernatur accusamus ullam laudantium, blanditiis, deserunt totam voluptates quas nostrum enim non quos obcaecati minus iure maiores dignissimos.</div>
  <a class="btn_elements" href="/test/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Text Button</a>


  <div>Modi, doloremque dolores quas, expedita sint, deserunt perspiciatis repellendus tenetur neque repellat sit error harum perferendis provident enim rem in. Consequatur nostrum error praesentium unde, vel voluptas ea quae neque.</div>
  <div>Ullam maxime atque delectus inventore, esse, cum, est soluta, dicta omnis placeat ducimus vel eveniet perspiciatis aperiam distinctio minima minus! Magnam fugiat nulla natus, quis doloremque? Ullam nesciunt, atque a.</div>
  <div>Voluptatem est, fugiat dignissimos consequuntur ut rerum rem doloribus blanditiis perferendis tempora expedita recusandae placeat voluptatum esse sit unde, sint culpa saepe error architecto soluta itaque fuga minima. Perferendis, praesentium!</div>
  <div>Earum cupiditate, minus dolorem harum aliquam qui aspernatur illum recusandae officia laborum ullam incidunt deserunt? Quibusdam qui odit earum, minima ea molestiae ad, dolorem unde, voluptatibus repellat accusantium dicta harum.</div>
  <div>Aliquam reiciendis laboriosam aliquid illo saepe, earum est voluptatibus, nostrum, dolorem similique, rerum? Culpa laudantium repellat similique! Blanditiis, neque aliquam harum atque, aspernatur maxime porro totam, nulla quibusdam voluptatibus itaque.</div>
  <div>Provident expedita, quo temporibus soluta voluptas, dolor dolorem quod voluptate eum, modi quibusdam a dicta doloremque neque voluptatum rerum totam sit vel blanditiis at quasi. Soluta unde dolores libero porro!</div>
  <div>Dolorum eius fugiat vel, suscipit repellat mollitia quas at facilis alias dignissimos illum quod, tempora ad ullam similique voluptates ea laboriosam possimus quia. Sit harum quam pariatur, suscipit libero inventore!</div>
  <div>Quod pariatur, natus minus doloribus nobis! Cum illo, repellat molestiae reiciendis quibusdam minus atque itaque dignissimos voluptatum quaerat magni quo debitis enim vel numquam. Laudantium, iste, soluta! Ipsum officia, odit!</div>
  <div>Explicabo quas possimus, iure hic reiciendis laudantium illum, natus minima! Quam blanditiis porro, placeat dolore in nesciunt numquam mollitia molestias? Qui quasi rem ut obcaecati cum at, corrupti adipisci aperiam.</div>
  <div>Inventore fugiat, ab reprehenderit quod sapiente! Corrupti, reprehenderit voluptatibus deleniti laboriosam, quod omnis neque itaque! Id eveniet facere ut, ducimus laborum nemo laboriosam voluptatibus ex ipsa reiciendis animi incidunt mollitia.</div>
  <div>Sapiente dignissimos repellat fugit excepturi beatae provident saepe, at eligendi voluptatum nesciunt ullam, nobis eius perspiciatis voluptatibus recusandae quia cupiditate possimus cumque eos quod aliquam harum. Minima ex labore amet.</div>
  <div>Minima voluptatem ex accusantium qui perspiciatis, officia, totam harum fugit nisi neque minus a illo voluptates quas dicta magnam obcaecati aut quos nemo veniam ducimus quam sequi similique unde laudantium?</div>
  <div>Culpa quod blanditiis aliquam tenetur reprehenderit a vel, laboriosam unde ut molestiae. Quo quibusdam ad sapiente, nisi amet et aut error voluptatibus molestias veniam quos enim vel ipsa. Dolorem, totam?</div>
  <div>Blanditiis, quia. Blanditiis asperiores quos id, totam tenetur animi tempora, consectetur hic quidem magni iusto eveniet consequatur laboriosam quibusdam nulla sint sed, iure alias aperiam veritatis sit eaque! Ipsum, similique!</div>
  <div>Reprehenderit repellat temporibus, voluptas cupiditate in, obcaecati, totam ipsa impedit rem, consequatur maxime sequi! Quas atque harum deleniti aspernatur aliquam, ea alias perspiciatis sunt a ad at maiores impedit amet!</div>
  <div>Sint qui, accusantium libero vero autem sapiente, eum illo nihil, voluptas ipsa quia! Animi ipsa dicta aperiam et ipsum beatae autem quis quaerat sit veritatis doloribus, non, consequuntur quae quam.</div>
  <div>A eius quia hic quam asperiores ipsum eum adipisci libero, ad enim eveniet voluptatum repudiandae assumenda reiciendis sint animi recusandae illum qui doloribus ut mollitia minima ab dicta accusamus! Quos.</div>
  <div>A, quo vel quam laudantium ipsam ipsa nesciunt incidunt nemo hic, vero eum. Est quam laboriosam nobis aspernatur labore ab neque laborum inventore similique. Culpa eaque asperiores atque minus, fugiat.</div>
  <div>Soluta, voluptates, autem. Atque commodi tempore ratione, inventore perferendis voluptatum? Neque distinctio ullam tempora magni corrupti maiores repudiandae, ex minus alias eius natus veritatis enim deserunt quam odit, cumque similique.</div>
  <div>Eum quia maiores ipsum porro doloribus fuga earum nam, laborum mollitia. Veniam distinctio culpa corporis, nam asperiores molestias quidem atque, quam dolor, excepturi tempore deserunt maiores aspernatur vero aperiam voluptate?</div>
  <div>Consequuntur ab voluptatem reprehenderit cum repudiandae, officia quia alias, nemo aliquam! Sit, perferendis! Odio deleniti doloribus optio, repellendus, beatae velit in aliquam voluptatem molestias earum, dignissimos eum dolore nihil dolorum.</div>
  <div>Corrupti quaerat qui commodi, maxime quis laudantium hic veritatis nulla! Culpa vel repellendus eligendi, sit corrupti saepe nesciunt ut beatae placeat blanditiis ipsa illo delectus repellat, sapiente totam, maxime id!</div>
  <div>Nobis, ratione distinctio eum, totam odit inventore minus sint obcaecati accusamus voluptatum explicabo veritatis nostrum temporibus soluta ad sapiente at beatae mollitia consectetur expedita qui tenetur alias. Eaque, quaerat atque!</div>
  <div>Eos repudiandae architecto, ad perspiciatis iusto voluptatum dicta. Rem modi fugiat animi et, natus est id necessitatibus harum illo doloribus voluptatem eligendi aliquam quasi magni assumenda voluptatum aperiam officiis, a.</div>
  <div>Quas repellat libero ipsam odit molestias cum tempore inventore, rem magni maxime recusandae accusamus dolores sint accusantium velit, soluta labore sunt ad exercitationem. Magni similique placeat, atque beatae. Odit, nisi!</div>
  <div>Adipisci ipsum nemo saepe ad rerum, necessitatibus iste aperiam. Dolorem ex praesentium ut amet molestias velit incidunt facere officia facilis, odit sapiente aliquam voluptates qui necessitatibus eligendi assumenda ipsam quisquam.</div>
  <div>Quam, tenetur. Quaerat doloremque ex voluptates nulla numquam. Quis soluta sint natus fugit, at iste, eligendi tempore voluptatem repellat eum minima, architecto modi officiis quo. Provident reiciendis illo voluptates atque!</div>
  <div>Reiciendis quisquam labore facere reprehenderit iste aliquid eveniet doloribus iure, ea, tempore nostrum aut culpa totam nisi ipsam necessitatibus temporibus quam velit rerum commodi, debitis. Soluta quaerat rerum, odit maxime.</div>
  <div>Laudantium distinctio molestias delectus eligendi placeat voluptatum natus nobis illum pariatur odit doloribus est consequuntur dolores consectetur id provident sapiente, error et eos. Voluptas, tenetur! Delectus, eligendi! Unde consequuntur, eaque.</div>
  <div>Repellat necessitatibus, perferendis dolorum obcaecati fugiat corporis praesentium quia ipsum, ipsa quas dolore reiciendis quasi enim amet assumenda atque earum dolor debitis deleniti. Ratione repellat vero, fuga, autem obcaecati praesentium.</div>
  <div>Nesciunt debitis laboriosam repudiandae, expedita eos iste ullam, officia recusandae facilis molestias, consectetur eligendi voluptatibus omnis asperiores et minima eius ea magnam necessitatibus! Quae asperiores, qui totam iste aliquam similique.</div>
  <div>Sequi autem sapiente at, sint minima maxime officiis! Illo, doloremque voluptatem assumenda quis eos amet sapiente suscipit sunt ex maiores quas vitae nulla non repellendus officiis rem quia, eius natus.</div>
  <div>Dolorem atque magnam magni veritatis suscipit sequi saepe minima blanditiis quo, neque aperiam libero iure dolorum. Animi ex a, et alias consectetur, debitis aliquid nihil, fugiat dolor dolore repellat id.</div>
  <div>Amet, nemo nobis repellat culpa aut deserunt sit nam ullam voluptatem non, modi eaque voluptate nesciunt praesentium velit? Aperiam velit, veniam harum laborum possimus illum quos corporis? Saepe, libero aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Veniam tenetur mollitia perspiciatis obcaecati ea perferendis in, officiis placeat inventore hic eius dolor aliquid consectetur! Itaque fugiat quod aperiam? At nulla odit cum fugit molestiae, reiciendis nobis quaerat suscipit?</div>
</div>

<div class="other_block">Test 2Veniam tenetur mollitia perspiciatis obcaecati ea perferendis in, officiis placeat inventore hic eius dolor aliquid consectetur! Itaque fugiat quod aperiam? At nulla odit cum fugit molestiae, reiciendis nobis quaerat suscipit?</div>
```

Comment: Нет, там ведь в конце вопроса дополнено. Необходимо, что бы доскролив до липкого элемента, он прилипался к нижней части экрана. Не раньше

Comment: @BlackStar1991, переделал.